# Code igniter 3.1.7 and php 7.1 sessions not working well

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-7.1

Am using code igniter 3.1.7 along side php7.1,  but every time i set a session and refresh the navigate to another controller method or redirect, it unsets it. here is how am setting the session.

```
$user=[
    "user_id"=>$_user['id'],
    "user_role"=>$_user['user_role'],
    "username"=>$_user['username'], 
    "role_name"=>$role_name,
    'bond'=>$_user['bond']
];

 $this->session->set_userdata($user);
```

Comment: need some more info.did u check session in another controller. by the way have u loaded session library?

Comment: i do check for the session in another controller and thats how i get the redirect, this system is already published on another linux box running PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23  and the session is working very well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $user=array(
    "user_id"=>$_user['id'],
    "user_role"=>$_user['user_role'],
    "username"=>$_user['username'], 
    "role_name"=>$role_name,
    'bond'=>$_user['bond']
    );

 $this->session->set_userdata($user);
```

For further information you can check official documents
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: php version 5.4 and higher support short array syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: this is probably not an issue because the same array syntax works in other parts on the code

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved after I replace the file system with the new version 3.1.9.

Don't forget to back up your work